# How to get partition's free space in a linux machine

Tags: linux, hard-drive

I have to get harddisk's free space available from 7 Windows 2008 servers and 4 Linux machines. For windows machines I wrote a tiny .Net Program. This will get details from all windows machines. 
In Linux machine I used

```
df -h
```

command. And I used the following command

```
ssh username@linuxmachine df -h
```

to get details from other Linux machine. But this command asks for password every time. Is there any way to get hard disk details from all Linux machines ? 
OR is there any way to get Linux machine's partition's details from a windows machine ?

All Linux machines have same username and password.

PS: I don't have any knowledge on shell scripting. kindly elaborate your solutions :)

Comment: You could use a passphraseless ssh key.

Here is a how to for it passphraseless ssh key http://wiki.hands.com/howto/passphraseless-ssh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use public/private key pairs for authentication. First generate public/private key. On linux you can do this:

```
ssh-keygen
```

You can find the keys in your homedir in .ssh :

```
ceco@persika ~/.ssh $ ls id_rsa*
id_rsa  id_rsa.pub
```

Then distribute public key on the machines you want to log in:

```
ssh-copy-id MACHINE_IP_ADDR
```

It will ask you for password and you are good to go. The public key is saved in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. After this procedure you can make passwordless logins. I won't discuss security risks about this - I believe you are aware what might go wrong :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try this.  Could you please provide me  a shell script for getting free spaces from all Linux machines ?

Comment: Your command should do the job (ssh username@linuxmachine df -h).